# Join five array values into a single array where all the array variable is same and the array contents are different javascript

Tags: javascript

here I have written a javascript where the array (var a=[""]) consists of different values in each if condition, I want all the array values to be stored in a single array seperated by comma(,). can anybody help me??

Here is my javascript

```
<script>
    function colorchange(id) {

    var background = document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor;

    if (background == "rgb(255, 145, 0)") {
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = "rgb(26,255,0)";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = "rgb(255, 145, 0)";
    }

    var elem = document.getElementById(id);

    if (id == "select") {
        if (elem.innerHTML == "Ignore Select") {
            elem.innerHTML = "Enable Select";
            var a = ["SELECT"]; //array returns SELECT
        } else {
            elem.innerHTML = "Ignore Select";
        }
    }

    if (id == "select1") {
        if (elem.innerHTML == "Ignore Delete") {
            elem.innerHTML = "Enable Delete";
            var a = ["DELETE"]; //array returns DELETE
        } else {
            elem.innerHTML = "Ignore Delete";
        }
    }

    if (id == "select2") {
        if (elem.innerHTML == "Ignore Insert") {
            elem.innerHTML = "Enable Insert";
            var a = ["INSERT"]; //array returns INSERT
        } else {
            elem.innerHTML = "Ignore Insert";
        }
    }

    if (id == "select3") {
        if (elem.innerHTML == "Ignore Update") {
            elem.innerHTML = "Enable Update";
            var a = ["UPDATE"]; //array returns UPDATE
        } else {
            elem.innerHTML = "Ignore Update";
        }
    }

    if (id == "select4") {
        if (elem.innerHTML == "Ignore Sleep") {
            elem.innerHTML = "Enable Sleep";
            var a = ["Sleep"]; //array returns Sleep
        } else {
            elem.innerHTML = "Ignore Sleep";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I want all the array return value to be stored in a single array,the array should be as 
"var x=[SELECT,DELETE,INSERT,UPDATE,Sleep];",variable x contains all the values seperated by comma(,) .How can I get this using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty array at the start of your function like this:

```
var x = []; // doesn't *need* to be empty
```

Then to add values call the push function like this:

```
x.push( "INSERT" );
```

If you want to return the array from your function write

```
return x;
```

FYI: Array values are not *actually* separated by comma's. That is simply how array values are coded and displayed to you as a coder/user. Each array element is like a separate variable. For example:

```
var x = [1,2,3];
// will show a popup where array elements are displayed separated by the default: comma
alert( x ); 
// will show a popup where array elements are displayed separated by semicolon
alert( x.join(";") );
```

Comment: When you alert an array, it returns values seperated by comma. http://jsfiddle.net/9bGx8/

Comment: Comma is simply the default separator for display and coding purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You are now clearing the array every time you change it. To add values to array, use this:

```
var a = [];
```

Then you can add values without clearing the full array:

```
a[a.length] = 'new_value';
```

Or you can use `.push`

```
a.push('new_value');
```

Comment: I really don't like this pattern of pushing elements much. It's more error prone and slower (a.length needs to be interpreted).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can add new elements to the end of the array using the `push` method:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push("a");
arr.push("b");
arr.push("c");
```

The above code results in an array the same as:

```
var arr = ["a","b","c"];
```

I'm not sure whether the string representation you mentioned is important or just you trying to illustrate what you want.

If you do want that string representation (`["a","b","c"]`) you need to encode the array as [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Answer (score 0):

to get array value seprated by comma, you just have to use toString() function for array.

Example :

```
var a = [];
a.push(1);
a.push(2);
a.push(3);
// comma seprated value
var b= a.toString();  // "1,2,3"
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the output by storing the values into array based on button values and retriving the value based on button values seperately...

Comment: Quite a few people spent some time on answering your question. The least you could do is: "describe clearly what the solution was, if it wasn't any of the answers above". If it was any of these answers above, you should mark it as the correct answer.